# Set the font size for a special math symbol by `\mathscr`

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I need to manually set the font size of a special math symbol by `\mathscr` for which the `\fontsize{<size>}{<size>}\selectfont` does not work. Here my sample is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{fix-cm}


\begin{document} \noindent

\fontsize{300}{300}\selectfont{\(\mathscr{G}\)}\par
\fontsize{300}{300}\selectfont{\(G\)}\par

\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 7):

The `mathrsfs` package only provides the font at fixed sizes (there are historical reasons for this).

You can provide a fully scalable version yourself; it's similar to what `fix-cm` actually does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <-6> rsfs5
   <7-9> rsfs7
   <9-> rsfs10
}{}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{300}{300}\selectfont
G\(\mathscr{G}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `xelatex` or  `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

    \fontsize{300}{300}\selectfont \(\mathscr{G} G\) 

\end{document}
```

[image]